# Disable Basic Authentication while using Spring Security Java configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I am trying to secure a  web application using Spring Security java configuration.

This is how the configuration looks:-

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private String googleClientSecret;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserService customUserService;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.
     * WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
     * #configure(org.springframework.security.config
     * .annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/","/static/**", "/resources/**","/resources/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
            .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        // @formatter:on
        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth
            .eraseCredentials(true)
            .userDetailsService(customUserService);
        // @formatter:on
        super.configure(auth);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have explicitly disabled HTTP Basic authentication using:-

```
.httpBasic().disable()
```

I am still getting HTTP Authenticaton prompt box while accessing a secured url. Why?

Please help me fix this.
I just want to render the default login form that comes bundled.

Spring Boot Starter Version : 1.1.5
Spring Security Version : 3.2.5

Thanks

Comment: add `security.basic.enabled=false` to your `application.properties`. Also you shouldn't be calling `super.configure` from your overridden method.

Comment: @M.Deinum  That fixed it. But why it wasn't disabled when I explicitly disabled in java config?

Comment: You can have multiple `WebSecurityConfigurer` each contributing configuration to the overall configuration. It very well could be that you have a rest part of your website that is protected by basic auth and the normal site with a form. You could create 2 `WebSecurityConfigurer` one for rest and one for form. You also might want to checkout http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html (Spring Boot reference, security section).

Comment: @M.Deinum you don't need to call the original implementation in the *Configurer classes, they just implement all methods of the interface with an empty body, so you can just override what you want to use.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, `security.basic.enabled=false` is no longer available. Any other solution. @M.Deinum

Answer (score 22):

First of all, calling `super.configure(http);` will override whole your configuration you have before that.

Try this instead:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .httpBasic().disable();
```

Comment: small correction.. should be .httpBasic().disable().

Comment: I apologize, but Im new to java, we are using jhipster with angular front and java back-end.  Where do I insert this code?  Is this in gateway? or micorservice? what file should be looking for?  Thanks -

Comment: @GelSisaed that might be a separate question altogether. Generally, it depends on where you are doing your auth, but with jhipster, doing auth in the gateway is pretty typical, so that is where I would start. It also wouldn't be a bad idea to post your own question (with a jhipster tag) like "How do I disable HTTP Basic in JHipster?"

Answer (score 8):

In case you use Spring Boot, the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html) states:

> To switch off the Boot default configuration completely in a web
>   application you can add a bean with @EnableWebSecurity

So if you want to fully customize itself that might be an option.

Just to make it clear... You just need to put @EnableWebSecurity annotation on your main application class or application configuration class.

Comment: This didn't work for me (I put @EnableWebSecurity on my main Spring Boot class and extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter). What it actually means to 'add a bean with @EnableWebSecurity'?

Comment: is this still a valid solution @marcel-overdijk ?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the formLogin through the HttpSecurity instance as follow:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated() 
        .and().formLogin().disable();
```

This will lead receiving 403 Http error when trying to access any secured resource

Answer (score 4):

Anonymous option worked for me. My code like

```
  http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and().
   authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous().and().httpBasic().disable();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Suitable for Spring Boot or folks using OAuth**

```
@Profile("test")
@EnableWebSecurity
static class BasicWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous().and().httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

If you are using @EnableOAuth2Client or @EnableResourceServer, then in test profile switch to basic auth and then disable the same. In Spring Boot,to switch off the spring security default configuration completely in a web application you need to add a bean with @EnableWebSecurity

Answer (score -9):

The following worked for me:

```
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Comment: This will not disable basic security, it will simply ignore the security checking for all requests.