# How to turn off Spring Security in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I have implemented authentication in my Spring Boot Application with Spring Security.

The main class controlling authentication should be websecurityconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/config/application.properties" })
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(
                    SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ristore/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler());
    }
```

Since I am doing OAuth, I have `AuthServerConfig` and `ResourceServerConfig` as well. My main application class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EntityScan({"org.mdacc.ristore.fm.models"}) 
public class RistoreWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
   @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(RistoreWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
         return application.sources(RistoreWebApplication.class);
     }
}
```

Since we are doing code consolidation, we need to turn off authentication temporarily. However, I tried the following methods and nothing seems to work. I am still getting 401 when I hit these rest api urls.

1. Comment out all the annotations in classes related to security including `@Configuration`, `@EnableWebSecurity`. In [Spring boot Security Disable security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security), it was suggested at the bottom adding `@EnableWebSecurity` will DISABLE auth which I don't think make any sense. Tried it anyway, did not work.
2. Modify websecurityconfig by removing all the security stuff and only do 
            `http
               .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().permitAll();`

[Disable Basic Authentication while using Spring Security Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639188/disable-basic-authentication-while-using-spring-security-java-configuration).   Does not help either.

3. Remove security auto config

   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
       org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
       org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})

like what they did in [disabling spring security in spring boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280181/disabling-spring-security-in-spring-boot-app). However I think this feature only works with `spring-boot-actuator` which I don't have. So didn't try this.

What is the correct way disable spring security?

Comment: Adding `@EnableWebSecurity` disables Spring Boot security auto configuration. In your case, you already have this annotation so you do not leverage auto configuration anyway. I suggest trying to comment out `@EnableWebSecurity` from your class and exclude `SecurityAutoConfiguration.class` from auto configuration.

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak Should I exclude SecurityAutoConfiguration.class in application class?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639188/disable-basic-authentication-while-using-spring-security-java-configuration#25740336)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot Security Disable security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @Maciej Walkowiak mentioned, you should do this for your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MainClass {
```

Comment: It works after adding this in my Main Application class and commenting out `@EnableWebSecurity` in my securityconfig class like what @MaciejWalkowiak said.

Comment: Now it's `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration`

Answer (score 4):

**try this**

1->Comment annotation @EnableWebSecurity in your security config

> //@EnableWebSecurity

2->Add these lines in your security config

> spring.security.enabled=false
>
> management.security.enabled=false
>
> security.basic.enabled=false

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this. Creating WebFilter and `PermitAll` Request Exchange and disabling CSRF.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain chain(ServerHttpSecurity http, AuthenticationWebFilter webFilter) {
        return http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .build();
    }
```

Just put this code in `@SpringBootApplication` class, Like this and will work like charm

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConverterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConverterApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain chain(ServerHttpSecurity http, AuthenticationWebFilter webFilter) {
        return http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .build();
}
```