# How to disable the default AuthenticationManager when implementing a Spring-Boot ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to setup a OAuth2 Resource Server using Spring-Boot. So far this is all working but still the *Using default security password:* logging shows up which I want to get rid of. This is what my configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuthConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

I already tried to add `@EnableWebSecurity`, `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` and Force it before and after SecurityAutoConfiguration but nothing seems to help. I also found some post on the net. The suggested config security.basic.enabled=false didn't work for me.

Anyone who knows how this is done correctly?

Comment: You may find your answer in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know this documentation but I wasn't able to get rid of the configuration with the hints from that. Actually the basic authentication doesn't work and my configured OAuth2 authentication does. But the log looks like there was some default security config that could be used to attack the service and even the password logged in plain there. I don't want this to trigger our security department. Therefore it needs to go away.

Comment: See accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228036/how-to-turn-off-spring-security-in-spring-boot-application
Worked for me, but I had to use together with `security.basic.enabled=false` property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off Spring Security in Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228036/how-to-turn-off-spring-security-in-spring-boot-application)

Comment: @Innokenty It's not a duplicate of the mentioned question. I do not want to disable spring security but only get rid of part of the default config.

Comment: true, but the accepted answer there is not disabling security as a whole, it only disables autoconfig.