# How to enable spring basic authentication only on a specific profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using `spring-boot-security` for basic authentication on my `@RestController` endpoints, as follows:

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=pass
```

Question: how can I disable the basic auth in development, and only enable it if a specific profile is active using startup parameter `-Dspring.profiles.active=production`.

I would like to move the properties above into `application-production.properties`. And in dev there should not be any auth on the endpoints.

Comment: From a security perspective, do it the other way around. Always enable security and disable for the dev profile... (You don't want to accidentally run unsecured in production!). Just add an `application-dev.properties` which disables security with `security.basic.enabled=false`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639188/disable-basic-authentication-while-using-spring-security-java-configuration

Comment: @M.Deinum great, would you add this as an answer so I can accept it? That's what I was looking for, without having to add any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a security perspective you probably want to do the opposite. Enable security by default and disable when running with a `dev` profile. Which is actually pretty easy to do add an `application-dev.properties` (assuming your profile is named `dev`.

Add the following to the file

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

And for dev start with the profile enabled.

Comment: Guys, this property is deprecated since Boot 2.x. Check detail info -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/49717573/4729203